# How do i use two different jquery scripts in same page?

Tags: jquery

Hello i am a newbie when it comes to jquery i have tried to use two scripts in the same page but they just wont work , i have tried using the noconflict but im a littel unsure how to properly implement it my code below is as follows.

```
    <html>
     <head>
        <title>example code</title>
        <script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     </head>
      <body>
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
          <li><img src="images/flexslider_images/cross_platform_image.png" alt="elite it designs using w3c compliant coding to create responsive websites" title="responsive website design"/></li></ul>
       <script src="scripts/jquery.flexslider.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  SyntaxHighlighter.all();
});
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",

  });
});
```

the above slider needs the 2.0.2 library to work the next is as follows.

```
   <div class="ms-display-template">
    <div class="ms-display-cont">
        <img src="images/display.png" class="ms-display-bg" />
        <div class="ms-dis-slider-cont">
            <!-- masterslider -->
            <div class="master-slider ms-skin-default" id="masterslider">
                <div class="ms-slide">
                    <img src="images/blank.gif" data-src="images/1.jpg" alt="lorem ipsum dolor sit"/>  
                </div></div></div></div></div>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Master Slider -->
    <script src="scripts/masterslider.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript"> 

 var slider = new MasterSlider();
    slider.setup('masterslider' , {
        width:507,
        height:286,
        speed:20,
        preload:0,
        space:2,
        view:'flow'
    });
    slider.control('arrows');   
    slider.control('bullets',{autohide:false});

</script>
```

this needs the 1.10.2 to work , when one works the other does not would someone please be able to give me a step by step instruction on how to actually do this please. like i said i am new to this.

thank you in advance for your help.

Adam

Comment: Why cant you just leave the 2.0.2 and remove the 1.10.2?

Comment: @user814628 At a guess, the jQuery API changes enough with the major version that neither script will work unmodified with the other's required version. Unfortunately, there's no really good way around the need to modify or replace one or the other -- see the answer I'm about to post.

Comment: Do you realize what browser 2.0.2 supports? Hopefully you do not need old IE8. :)

Comment: Wait a minute! It says [here](http://jquery.com/download/) that there are no breaking API changes in 2.0 -- indeed, no API changes at all, just removal of support for obsolete IE versions. Any plugin that works with 1.10 should therefore work with 2.0 -- so, @adam, what's actually going wrong? If you'll edit your question to describe the problem you're seeing, ideally with whatever Javascript console output (especially errors) you're getting along with the misbehavior, that'll make it a lot more likely you get a useful answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [noConflict method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), with a `true` argument, to try to work around this. But there's a major drawback:

> If necessary, you can free up the `jQuery` name as well by passing `true` as an argument to the method. This is rarely necessary, and if you must do this (for example, if you need to use multiple versions of the jQuery library on the same page), you need to consider that most plug-ins rely on the presence of the `jQuery` variable and may not operate correctly in this situation.

That is, if, after the `<script>` tag you use to load jQuery 2.0.2, you inserted

```
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict(true)</script>
```

the global `jQuery` variable would then represent jQuery 1.10.2, undoing the override applied when you load the 2.0.2 version.

What you *can't* do, though, is somehow have the same global variable represent both versions, which means you're almost certainly still going to have the problem of one or the other script failing to work -- even if you do some fancy footwork so that each plugin sees `jQuery` pointing to the library version it expects at initialization time, the given documentation excerpt suggests a strong likelihood that both scripts will attempt to reference the global `jQuery` variable in event handlers or similar, which means, again, that at least one of them isn't going to work.

In theory, you might be able to hack your way around this with some *really* fancy footwork to ensure that each plugin's callbacks see the `jQuery` value they expect -- but depending on what those plugins do, that may not even be possible, and even if it were, the result would almost certainly be unmaintainable.

tl;dr The way to solve your problem is to standardize on a single version of jQuery, and either find plugins which work with that version and do what you need, or else pick one plugin and modify it so that it works with the jQuery version you're using. (I'd recommend sticking with 1.10, since it won't have the 2.0 breaking changes and will therefore have a much broader range of plugins available to work with it.)

Answer (score -1):

Using no conflict code will solve your problem.

```
<script src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

here is the full reference : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Hope that answers your question.
Shafi Ur Rahman

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, this answer doesn't address the problem at hand -- what you're describing only works when you've got two different libraries arguing over the global `$` variable. When you've got two different versions of jQuery arguing over the global `jQuery` variable, this doesn't solve the problem, and really nothing else does either -- see my answer for more.